# Number of non zero entries in jordan canonical form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A $ be $7 \times 7$ matrix such that $2A^2 -A^4 =I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.
If $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues each with geometric multiplicity $3$,
 how many non zero entries are there in Jordan canonical form of $A$?

Comment: Where is the difficulty for you?

Comment: Do we have to use minimal polynomial to make Jordan canonical form?

Comment: You were already told its roots and their multiplicities implicitly in the description of the question, so you don't have to construct it.

Comment: Roots are 1and -1...

Answer (score 2):

If there are only two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, then their algebraic multiplicity must add up to 7. Let the algebraic multiplicity be given by $a_1,a_2$. Then $a_1+a_2=7$.

If each one of the eigenvalues has geometric multiplicity 3, that means that $a_1\geq 3,a_2 \geq 3$. This implies that either $a_1=4,a_2=3$ or $a_1=3,a_2=4$. Let's assume the former.

This would imply that $\lambda_2$ will have a full set of eigenvectors while $\lambda_1$ will not. Recall that the number of Jordan blocks associated with an eigenvalue is equal to the geometric multiplicity of that eigenvalue. So for an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 3 that has a full set of eigenvectors (geometric multiplicity = 3), then there will be 3 1x1 Jordan blocks for that eigenvalue.

Then, following the same rule, the number of Jordan blocks associated with $\lambda_1$ will be 3. Then we must have 2 1x1 blocks and 1 2x2 block.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: What do you know about Jordan blocks?

Comment: For this there will be two possibility for making Jordan canonical forms..just show me the first one.....

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more info. Is it more clear now?

Comment: We have given an equation in the question can't we find eigen values from that?? How did we come to know that their will be one 2x2 Jordan block

Comment: A is 7x7, so J must be also 7x7, and since the # of Jordan blocks is equal to the algebraic multiplicity, $\lambda_2$ has 3 Jordan blocks and their dimensions must add to 3 and  $\lambda_1$ has 3 Jordan blocks and their dimensions must add to 4.

Comment: Can't we have all 1x1 block then also it will add up to 4 for $\lambda_ 1$?